# ErroCS1929 'IHtmlHelper<IPagedList<Book>>' does not contain a definition for 'PagedListPager'

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, paging

This is the full error

> 

Error   CS1929  'IHtmlHelper<IPagedList>' does not contain a definition for 'PagedListPager' and the best extension method overload 'HtmlHelper.PagedListPager(HtmlHelper, IPagedList, Func<int, string>)' requires a receiver of type 'HtmlHelper'   BookSystem  E:\source\TelerikAlpha\BookSystem\BookSystem\Views\Manage\Index.cshtml  52  Active

And all I followed was the code in microsoft's tutorial for paging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Does anyone have any idea why it happens like this?

Comment: Are you using `ASP.NET` or `ASP.NET Core` ?  You're following a tutorial for `ASP.NET`.

Comment: For ASP.NET Core , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564713/errocs1929ihtmlhelperipagedlistbook-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-pa

Comment: May you provide the code that is generating the error? Linking to a tutorial isn´t of great help, as people will have to guess where the error is happening. You should give more info/code so others can help. Regards.

Comment: Alrighty then, but it really seemed that I was using an ASP NET approach on an ASP NET Core project. So I changed the approach and it worked, because Microsoft has tutorials for both ASP NET & ASP NET Core

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. There are many NuGet packages related to PagedList, so it's the matter of finding the right one.

For an MVC app, the NuGet package that I needed was X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.

To install this package in Visual Studio, go to Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution. Browse for X.PagedList.Mvc.Core and install it for your project.

In your view where you are implementing paging, add:

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core
```